# Vertical line that stretches when changing viewport but doesn't go past an html element

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/98eqcm5p/

I would like a vertical line next to the **h1** and **p** elements (to the left). I want it to stretch from the **top of the h1** element to the **bottom of the p** element, even if I change the viewport, without overstretching. How to achieve this?

I tried with a line that has absolute position, but that line goes past the html elements if I change to landscape mode.

```
<h1>
This is a cool title.
</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.
</p>

<h1>
This is a cool title.
</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.
</p>

<h1>
This is a cool title.
</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.
</p>

h1, p {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a border for this.

But you need to set the margins between h1 and p to 0, and change them with padding:

```css
h1, p {
  border-left: 3px solid green;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
This is a cool title.
</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.
</p>

<h1>
This is a cool title.
</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.
</p>

<h1>
This is a cool title.
</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Group the h1 and p elements into a section, article, or div and add a left border.
If you are not allowed to edit the HTML, then see [vals's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61167413/3221253).

```css
h1, p {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

section {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-left: 2px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<section>
<h1>
This is a cool title.
</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.
</p>
</section>

<section>
<h1>
This is a cool title.
</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.
</p>
</section>

<section>
<h1>
This is a cool title.
</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.Lorem ipsum incendius maraudon.
</p>
</section>
```